# Java 8 and lambdas in shutdown hook

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Sonar mentioned, that this java code should be used with lambda, but I have never used lamdas and have no idea how to use it. Can someone point me to the correct version of this code:?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        closeable.close();
        logger.info("Close closeable.");
        executorPool.shutdown();
        logger.info("Shutdown executorPool");
    }
}));
```

Comment: Then please refer to the lambda tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: In case, `executorPool` refers to an executor service like `ThreadPoolExecutor`, calling `shutdown()` on it inside a JVM shutdown hook makes not much sense, as `shutdown()` only *initiates* a shutdown of the thread pool, whether it ever has a chance to complete (or make progress at all) before the JVM kills all threads the hard way, is unpredictable. Not that there was any need to end the threads manually before the JVM ends them automatically…

Comment: You are right. If you use a executor service, it makes more sense to use shutdownNow, but I'm using another class and the naming here could be misleading for the reader.

Comment: Ahh now I'm not able to create new questions due to question ban@stackoverflow, because this one question was downvoted and my other questions have no attention ....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just replace `new Runnable()` with `() ->`

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
    closeable.close();
    logger.info("Close closeable.");
    executorPool.shutdown();
    logger.info("Shutdown executorPool");
 }));
```

Runnable is a functional interface, which means it only has one abstract method, so it can be replaced with a lambda expression, which is sort of *functionality than can be passed as argument*

Comment: Wow very fast. Thank you.

Comment: It would be great if addShutdownHook itself accepted a Runnable instance instead of an initialized thread, or at least accepted a [Supplier](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces#Suppliers) lambda which would lazily instantiate a thread hook.